# Book memory is not implicitly convertible to expected type string storage?? can anyone help me out with this?

Tags: solidity

Solidity error:

```
TypeError: Type struct smartcontract.Book memory is not implicitly convertible to expected type string storage ref.
  --> contracts/Solidity part 4 (Mapping).sol:24:33:
   |
24 |         mybooks[msg.sender][id]=Book(_title,_author);
   |   

                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0lysZ.png)[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have the wrong type in your definition of `mybooks`.

Change the line:

```
mapping(address=>mapping(uint=>string)) public mybooks;
```

to

```
mapping(address=>mapping(uint=>Book)) public mybooks;
```